# How to show route default value?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, routes

I have a route:

`"{culture}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
new { culture = "en", controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }`

The Url becomes

`http://mysite.com`

I want to show the culture name so that the url will look like this:

`http://mysite.com/en`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Defaults are always hidden

Defaults are always hidden as long as all values after it are provided with defaults as well. You will have to provide two route definitions:

```
"en/{controller}/{action}/{id}", new { culture = "en" , ... }

"{culture}/{controller}/{action}/{id}", ...
```

The first one will always add `en` after domain address for outbound links and will also process the request when an inbound request will start with `en` segment.

In case culture is different than English, second route will get hit and process inbound and outbound routing.

> **Note about [in/out]bound**:
>
> - *Inbound routing* processes requests when they hit your server
> - *Outbound routing* processes when you generate URLs on your views (links, form actions...)